# Hacer una redireccion desde el .htaccess de un dominio a un archivo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección

Quiero que cuando introduzca mi dominio me parezca directamente un pdf, tengo esto en el htaccess pero me aparece la carpeta raiz donde esta el archivo pdf

Redirect 301  http://midominio.es/ /archivo.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría con mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule !archivo\.pdf$ /archivo.pdf [L,R=301]
```

Esto redirecciona todas las peticiones que no van inicialmente a `archivo.pdf` a ese mismo archivo.